# How to adjust exposure of an image in php gd

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, php-gd

I read that exposure is the amount of light allowed to fall on each area unit of a photographic medium (photographic film or image sensor) during the process of taking a photograph, according to wiki. I am not from image processing background. So,I am still confused about it.

But I cannot find any tutorial on exposure adjustment using php. 
 Is there a way to develop exposure adjustment function in php gd?  Can anyone advise? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You should adjust brightness, not exposure. Once a JPG or BMP is already made, you can just brighten-up a pixel. The term "exposure" is properly used only while taking a digital image or developing negatives (analogue or digital).

GD has [imagefilter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefilter.php) function, you should probably use the `IMG_FILTER_BRIGHTNESS` filter type.

Comment: Thank. I have already adjusted brightness using Img-filter_brightness. But I am wondering whether we can adjust exposure in image editing tool like this website does.https://apps.facebook.com/picmonkey/ So, it means exposure is only for taking photos but not for image editing tools?

Comment: Well, many tools say "exposure" when they are actually just changing a photo's brightness and contrast levels. So you should try different combinations of filters and possibly even writing your own.